# i got set this coding task from my school and am having trouble doing the python code

Tags: python, calculator, flowchart

https://www.101computing.net/entry-fees-calculator-using-a-flowchart/

I was trying to do the coding challenge my school sent me (link attached above) and I got quite stuck so I was hoping if someone could help. I was stuck when trying to add the discount calculating part because I had to see if the price was more than 50 and if it was, apply a 5% discount to it

```py
def ThemePark():
    age = int(input('Enter age: '))
    if age <= 15:
        print("Your entry price is £11")
    if age >= 15:
        print("Your entry price is £13.50")
    if age >= 18:
        print("Your entry price is £15 ")
    discount = get_discount(price1 + price2 + price3)
    print_discount_message(discount)
    price > 50
    price1 = 11
    price2 = 13.50
    price3 = 15
    price > 50
    discountprice = calculate_discount_price(price, discount)
    print(f'  Your price: {discd} (original price: {price})')

def Discount(price):
    if price > 50:
        discount = 0.95
    else:
        discount = 0.0

    return discount

def print_discount_message(discount):
    if discount == 0.0:
        print('  Not qualified for family discount.')
    else:
        print('  Qualified for discount: {}%'.format(int(discount * 100)))

def calculate_discount_price(original_price, discount):
    return round(original_price - original_price * discount, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        ThemePark()
        more = input('Buy more? (Yes/No): ')
        if more != 'Yes':
            break
```

Comment: What do you hope code like `price > 50` should do in isolation?

Comment: When you get a little more experienced, you will find out why using floats (numbers with a decimal point in them) will not work correctly some of the time. For the time being, just trust us that you want to handle the amounts as integers - probably convert everything to cents (or is that pence in your currency?) and take it from there.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: An age of 15 will return True in both of the first two if statements. What would the price be for someone of age 15?

Answer (score -2):

def print_discount_message(discount):
if discount == 0.0:
print('  Not qualified for family discount.')
else:
print('  Qualified for discount: {}%'.format(int(discount * 100)))

To output the print('  Qualified for discount: {}%'.format(int(discount * 100)))
you should have:
print('  Qualified for discount: {}%'.format(int((1 - discount) * 100)))